# How can I figure out an unknown error in an X509Chain?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, x509certificate

I've got a program that calls web services at customer sites, and since the web service is provided by a third party it requires SSL and I can't do anything about it.

In most cases when there is an error it's because there is a self-signed certificate, so I am checking X509Chain.ChainElements.ChainElementStatus for the UntrustedRoot error and just ignoring it.

That's all fine, however I'm getting an error from a new client and the ChainElementStatus element just appears to be an empty array.  Any thoughts on what might cause that?  If I look at the certificate error in IE it just says the certificate was not issued by a trusted CA.

EDIT: Adding the trace as Markus suggested, I see the following error coming back:

> ```
> DateTime=2009-12-21T21:58:29.8719648Z
> ```
>
> System.Net Information: 0 : [0772]
>   SecureChannel#57280435 - Remote
>   certificate has errors:
>       ProcessId=4964
>       DateTime=2009-12-21T21:59:15.3239262Z
>   System.Net Information: 0 : [0772]
>   SecureChannel#57280435 -  An internal
>   certificate chaining error has
>   occurred.
>
> ```
> ProcessId=4964
> DateTime=2009-12-21T21:59:15.3239262Z
> ```
>
> System.Net Information: 0 : [0772]
>   SecureChannel#57280435 - Remote
>   certificate was verified as invalid by
>   the user.
>       ProcessId=4964

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding some more logging? That's gotten me out of couple a of related errors in the past (I once spent more hours than I care to remember debugging a certificate related issue only to realize that someone had set the clock forward to a time when my certificate was no longer valid).

I finnaly managed to locate the problem after reading Jeff P Sanders [great blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/jpsanders/archive/2009/09/16/troubleshooting-asp-net-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure.aspx) about the process of debugging certificate related errors. It's written for asp.net clients but it works equally well for regular .net clients.

The core of it is [adding a couple of trace listeners](http://blogs.msdn.com/jpsanders/archive/2009/03/24/my-favorite-system-net-trace-configuration-file-dumps-process-id-and-date-time-information.aspx) to your (App|Web).Config file. The one you're probably going to be most interested in is the tracewriter for System.Net and maybe System.Net.Sockets.

```
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
        <source name="System.Net">
            <listeners><add name="System.Net"/></listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
            <listeners><add name="System.Net"/></listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add
             name="System.Net"
             type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="System.Net.trace.log"
             traceOutputOptions = "ProcessId, DateTime"
         />
    </sharedListeners>
    <switches>
        <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
        <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Give it a go and if it doesn't solve your problem you should at least have enough data to update your question with more info.

Comment: Thanks!  Not getting a whole lot more info, but I added what I think is the relevant portion of the trace...